# How to disable the filename display at the top left corner in Neovim?

Tags: neovim

[image: screenshot of my neovim]

You can see that at the top left corner, Neovim displays the filename of the current editing file. I want to disable this feature as I find it quite annoying.

Here is my Neovim Version:

NVIM v0.8.3

Build type: Release

LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3

Compiled by runner@fv-az183-550

Comment: See `:help 'showtabline'`.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

`:set showtabline=1` to show tab names only when you have more than one tab.

`:set showtabline=0` to never show tab names.